# Nested Fragments and ViewPager issues on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter in combination with a view pager, which is nested in a fragment on Android. Thus, I am using the ChildFragmentManager in combination with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter to create my fragments.

So far so good, but here is the problem:

- If I open a different Activity without finishing the activity that hosts the fragment with the view pager and afterwards resume it, the fragment that was selected in the ViewPager is empty. If I switch the fragment in the ViewPager before I open the different Activity, this issue does not appear. After returning and seeing the empty Fragment in the ViewPager, I am still able to switch the next Fragments, but if I try to switch back to the empty Fragment, I get a NullPointerException. This issue does not occur if I switch between the Fragment hosting the ViewPager and a different Fragment or if I change orientations.
- If I use the FragmentManager instead of the ChildFragmentManager, I do not have this issue when switching to a different Activity, but it will then occur if I switch between the hosting and a different fragment or if I change the orientation.

So here's what I already tried without any success:
* Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter and FragmentPagerAdapter
* Use setRetainedInstance(true and false)
* Use getChildFragmentManager() and getFragmentManager()
* Override getItemPosition() return POSTION_NONE and use notifyDataChanged() in onResume()

The only thing that is currently doing the trick is recreating the PagerAdapter in onResume() and re-initializing the ViewPager, but I think that's really bad practice as everything needs to be recreated.

So is there somebody, who can explain to me how a correct implementation should look like, or why the fragments can become empty (they are not null, I checked that). I am searching for a more elegant solution rather than recreating everything each time I resume my activity.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Seem to recall that creating the adapter in onCreate of the fragment holding the viewpager can help in some situations.

Comment: can you maybe post some code for your adapter? I've been through hell on numerous occasions having similar issues using viewpagers

Comment: have similar issue and still trying to find the solution...